# Use Tokens to get the title of a node a form was submitted from

Tags: tokens, path-aliases

I have a bunch of nodes that contain forms on them that when submitted will create further nodes of another content type.

Using Token fields is it possible to have a field on the newly created nodes that will display the node title of the page that the node was created on (e.g its parent node)?

Another option is to do this, lets say I have a page called Foo, on the page "Foo" I use a form to create page "Bar" I want the url of page "Bar" to be something like www.drupal.com/Foo/Bar.

Is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: try using [node:source:title] or something related form here https://www.drupal.org/node/390482

Comment: This would be great, however it doesn't seem to work. Do I need to configure nodes in any way to set them as the "source" node?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to make URL aliases of nodes created via form include node title of original page?](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/144807/how-to-make-url-aliases-of-nodes-created-via-form-include-node-title-of-original)